# Exact sequences (homomorphism of short exact sequences)

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

Provided is a homomorphism of short exact sequences:

$$
\begin{array}
& 0 & \rightarrow & F_1 &  \overset{\varphi_1}{\rightarrow} & E_1 & \overset{\psi_1}{\rightarrow} & G_1 &  \rightarrow& 0 \\ 
&  & \varrho\downarrow & & \sigma\downarrow & & \tau\downarrow & & \\ 
0 & \rightarrow & F_2 &  \overset{\varphi_2}{\rightarrow} & E_2 & \overset{\psi_2}{\rightarrow} & G_2 &  \rightarrow& 0 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

I am asked to show that

$$\varphi_1(\text{ker}\varrho)=\text{ker}\sigma$$

but I do not know how to start. Could you give me a suggestion?

Comment: "The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries." -https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992 . For a new user, I recommend reading through the provided link, and learning how to use MathJax to type your questions. While certainly there may be merit to including an image here, your entire post should not be one.

Comment: Do you know how to show that two sets are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b \in \varphi_1 (\ker \rho)$, then existis $a\in \ker \rho$ such that $b=\varphi_1(a)$, then $\sigma(b)= \sigma(\varphi_1(a))$, now  $\sigma(b)= \varphi_2(\rho(a))$.
So $\sigma(b)=0$, then $b \in \ker(\sigma)$

Comment: and the other containment?